# How do I render a hash in a view where the key comes from the page itself?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

More detailed question: How do I render a hash in a view, where the hash is passed from the controller but the key comes from the page via Javascript?

I know I can do something like this `<%= hash["key"] %>`, but in my case `"key"` is coming from another hash element generated on my page with JS, call it js_hash.js_key.

I've tried the following to no avail

`<%= raw hash %>[js_hash.js_key]`

`<%= raw hash %>[js_hash["js_key"]]`

Comment: why is the key coming from javascript? are you trying to make an interactive element for the user to view hash items? like a drop down? also, are you using ruby on rails?

Comment: I am indeed using Rails.  

This is for an application using datatables.  I'm coloring the row based on a specific column's value, using a color map passed in from the controller.

This was already answered by another user max pleaner.  I'm not sure why his answer was deleted.

This worked (single quotes were important):   `'<%= the_hash.to_json.html_safe %>'`

Comment: Ah okay! Not sure why his answer was deleted, but if you're feeling up to it, you can make your own answer saying what worked, then accept that answer so everyone knows you got it figured out. ^-^

Comment: @eiko - done, thanks!

Comment: @Valkry I deleted it since it wasn't working the way I expected when I tested it ... but glad you figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked (single quotes were important):

`var some_js_var = JSON.parse('<%= the_hash.to_json.html_safe %>');
console.log(some_js_var[js_hash.js_key]);`